# Equivalent of Thymeleaf fragments in Velocity

Tags: thymeleaf, velocity

I used th:fragment a lot but currently I'm using Apache Velocity and I wonder if there is any equivalent. Unfortunately Google couldn't help me any further. Do you know any tricks or a Workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest thing I can think of is including other temple files:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Homepage</title>
   </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Welcome!!</h1>
     #include("./src/pageFooter.vm")
  </body>
</html>
```

Or using [Macros](http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch07.html)

```
#macro( tablerows $color $values )
  #foreach( $value in $values )
    <tr><td bgcolor=$color>$value</td></tr>
  #end
#end
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good solution. I just want to make my HTML files a little bit smaller.